# Writing instruction vs. assignment?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

What is the difference between "writing instruction" and "writing assignment (question)"? Which to use, in which situations?

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Can you give me a pointer on what you mean by "writing instruction"?  It's not a phrase I've heard before.

Comment: E. g. "The Journal of Second Language Writing is devoted to publishing theoretically grounded reports of research and discussions that represent a contribution to current understandings of central issues in second and foreign language writing and _writing instruction_." See: http://www.journals.elsevier.com/journal-of-second-language-writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Writing instruction" is what you'll get here.  Details on how to write things correctly, sentence construction and syntax.  Basically, details on how to write in the given language.

A "writing assignment" is something completely different, as it's a request for someone to write about a given subject.  Basically, an essay.

I hope that helps.